# Restkit- update of nested object result in error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have an api, say for example .../api/TodaysBeacon/ which returns the following data structure
Beacons

Beacon1 - BeaconAction1
This api returns only the BeaconAction that is applied for today, which means that if I request it yesterday, the result is as above, and if I request it today, the result could be as follows,

Beacons

Beacon1 - BeaconAction2
The data from the api is persisted locally and I have done the one (Beacon) to many (BeaconActions) mapping.

```
[beaconDataMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"BeaconActions"
                                                                                  toKeyPath:@"beaconAction"
                                                                                withMapping:beaconActionDataMapping]];
```

However, I am getting errors when my code request the api data today after requesting it at first yesterday.

**UserInfo=0x170664a40 {NSValidationErrorKey=beacon, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject= (entity: BeaconAction; id: 0xd000000000140000 x-coredata://28C42D7B-5172-47EF-81BA-BA629354E1AD/BeaconAction/p5 ; data: {...**

I am suspecting that the error is due to that BeaconAction1 is nested under Beacon1 and this gets persisted yesterday when the api was requested. Now when the api is requested today and restkit is trying to persist data again, it could not find BeaconAction1 any more from the result.

If I am right here, how can I fix this error?

The desired behaviour of my app is that BeaconAction1 remain persisted in the local store while BeaconAction 2 is added to the store as well.

Comment: What is the data model? It looks like you're creating a new partial beacon that isn't valid to be saved into Core Data... Presumably because you don't have a unique id on the object.

Comment: As Wain suggested, we would need more information to assist. Maybe some examples of your JSON response from the API would also help us answer your question. [identificationAttributes](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKEntityMapping.html#//api/name/identificationAttributes) is probably a good place for you to check out if that is not possible/reasonable.